# Control Back Navigation in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a search feature with a list view. When the user click on search and filters the result the activity is loaded from the beginning. So here is the flow.

User opens my application (Gets the whole list ot items) -> Search1 (Filtered search) -> Search2 (Filtered result 2)  -> Search3 (Filtered result 3). Now when the user clicks back he goes to Search 2 -> then back to result 1 -> then back to the mail list.

This is how is my application working now. I want this to change as when users is on any search result I want him to go back to main list without going back to any search results.

Basically I dont want android system to track the search results so that when user clicks back, he should directly go to the main list.

How do I do this. Please advice if you have any alternative for this. Thank you for your advice and time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your search activity to be `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in your manifest, that way there's a single search activity and you're only responding to search intents within it. This is actually the "ideal" behavior according to [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#LifeCycle).

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with the search results you could [finish](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) that activity. You might even be able to use [finishOnTaskLaunch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#finish) to achieve the same thing and it is probably more desirable too.